# Get nsf resource from a managed bean

Tags: xpages

I'm missing something. In Eclipse I drafted a class to make PDF and imported a couple of fonts into a the package and accessed them like this:

Font garamondBlue = FontFactory.getFont("/fonts/Garamond.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

I'm moving this to an XPage bean now, and I can't find how to get them the same way. I could put them in as file resources, but how do I access them there?

I added images to classic Java agents back in the pre-XPage days, can we do something like that with a bean?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read file resources as input streams like this:

```
InputStream fileResource = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream("filename");
```

Comment: Per, I am in your debt. That worked perfectly. Thank you. Using byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileResource); (imported from Apache commons) makes is a byteArray, which I needed. This works for images as well - which will make a it a lot easier.